# Pointer member mysteriously getting erased?

Tags: c++, pointers

So I have ClassA with a pointer, and a function to assign a value to that pointer:

```
class ClassA
{
private:
    SomeType* _someType;

public:
    void AssignSomeTypePtr(SomeType* someType) 
    {
        _someType = someType;
    }
};
```

I then have ClassB which creates the SomeType pointer, and assigns it to my ClassA classes, which are held in a vector:

```
class ClassB
{
private:
    std::vector<ClassA> _classes;

public:
    void MakeSomePointers(unsigned char* rawData)
    {
        SomeType* someType = reinterpret_cast<SomeType*>(rawData);
        for (auto A : _classes)
        {
            A.AssignSomeTypePtr(someType);
        }
    }
};
```

The problem arises when I want to call a function from my ClassA class that utilizes the SomeType pointer that was previously assigned by ClassB. For some reason, _someType no longer holds the address of which it was assigned by ClassB (it reverts back to its initialized value in the ClassA constructor, which is null).

I've been scratching my head for hours trying to figure out what's wrong. I've been coding basically nonstop for 4-5 hours, so I've probably hit that time period where I am making a basic mistake but for some reason it's going over my head. I've confirmed that the pointer assigned via the AssignSomePtr function does contain a valid address, and that _someType does get assigned that value. But when I call a function in the ClassA class that uses that pointer, all the sudden _someType == null. I AM assigning the value BEFORE I call this function, by the way.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

P.S. I know pointers equal bad news. Unfortunately I'm writing a file serialization library for a 3D game that has a very unique way of storing data, so serialization libraries such as boost are of zero help to me.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<SomeType*>` careful of pointer alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `for` cycle is written as in your original post, then `A` is a *local copy* of the current vector element. On each iteration of that `for` cycle you are assigning your pointer value to a *copy* of vector element and then immediately destroying that copy. The vector itself remains untouched.

You have to declare your cycle variable as a *reference* if you want to modify the actual vector elements

```
for (auto &A : _classes)
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ClassA, as presented in the question, will have default copy constructor and assignment operators.

Comment: I knew it was a simple overlook on my part. Thank you very much!